Is the partial order of all equations in the signature of magmas a lattice?
Consider the signature of a single binary operation $*$, and consider the set $Eq$ of all equations in that signature. I can define a preorder $\geq$ on $Eq$ by stipulating that $E \geq E'$ precisely when $E$ implies $E'$. I can now consider the partial order obtained by quotienting out the preorder by its standard equivalence relation. My question is, is this partial order a lattice? If not, is it at least a join semilattice or a meet semilattice? If not even that, is it still at least the case that for every pair of elements, either the pair has a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound? I would be very interested to be given a pair of equations such that they do not have either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound.
